# I want to delay jQuery ajax successful function

Tags: jquery, ajax, delay, replacewith

I want to let user wait for 2 seconds before the HTML inside the block changes.  Can you help me to set some time so that ajax request was not so fast and I had time to show some animation

I tried to set timeout but it is not working

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

$(document).on('click', '#wp-request', function(event){
             event.preventDefault(); 
             var path = myScript.pluginsUrl + '/simple/widget-final.php';
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
                                         url: path,
                                         cache: false,
      success : function(data){
      var newWidget = $(data); 
      $('#widget-container').replaceWith(newWidget);
      },
      error : function(){ alert('Error'); },
      dataType : 'html'
                });
    
});

$(document).on('click', '#wp-back', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var path = myScript.pluginsUrl + '/simple/widget-initial.php';
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
                                         url: path,
                                         cache: false,
      success : function(data){
      var newWidget = $(data); 
      $('#widget-container').replaceWith(newWidget);
      },
      error : function(){ alert('Error'); },
      dataType : 'html'
                });
    
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="widget-container">
<p>We are on first page</p>
<a id="wp-request" href="">Send</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Apply `setTimeout` inside the success callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `setTimeout` in your success callback function.

```
success : function(data){
    setTimeout(function(){
         var newWidget = $(data); 
         $('#widget-container').replaceWith(newWidget);
     },2000);  // The millis to wait before executing this block
},
```